# Passing array to function results in segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to build a quicksort function however it results in a `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Having read about this error I am sure that I have a stray pointer however I simply can't spot it. I also used valgrind to help me debug this and I will comment the lines that valgrind told me about in the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

  int partition(int *a,int l, int h, int pivot)
 {
  l++;
  while(l <= h && a[l] < a[pivot])
  {
    l++;
  }
  while(a[h] >= a[pivot])
  { //conditional jump depends on uninitialised value here
    h--;
  }
  if(l < h)
   {
    int tmp = a[l];
    a[l] = a[h];
    a[h] = tmp;
    partition(a,l,h,pivot);
   }
   else
   {
    int tmp = a[pivot];
    a[pivot] = a[h];
    a[h] = tmp;
    return h;
  }
 return -1;
}




void quicksort(int *a, int low, int high)
 {
  //base case.
  if(low - high == 0){
    return;
  }
  //just two elements in array to be sorted
  if(low - high == -1)
   {
    if (a[low] < a[high]) 
     {
      int tmp = a[low];
      a[low] = a[high];
      a[high] = tmp;
     } 
    else
    {
      return;
    }
  }
  else
  {
  //the actual algorithm
  int pivot = a[low];
  int j = partition(a,low,high,low); //caused by this (valgrind)
  int tmp = pivot;
  a[low] = a[j];
  a[j] = tmp;
  quicksort(a,0,j-1); //and this (valgrind)
  quicksort(a,j+1,high);
  }
}


  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  int a[] = {5,1,5,3,4,1};
  quicksort(a,0,5);
  int n = 0;
  while(n < 6)
   {
    printf("index %d is %d\n",n,a[n]);
    n++;
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated

Here is the output from Valgrind

```
==4698== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4698== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4698== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4698== Command: ./quicksort
==4698== 
==4698== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4698==    at 0x4005B8: partition (quicksort.c:9)
==4698==    by 0x40079E: quicksort (quicksort.c:46)
==4698==    by 0x400803: quicksort (quicksort.c:50)
==4698==    by 0x40081A: quicksort (quicksort.c:51)
==4698==    by 0x400803: quicksort (quicksort.c:50)
==4698==    by 0x400803: quicksort (quicksort.c:50)
==4698==    by 0x40086B: main (quicksort.c:61)
==4698== 
==4698== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4698==    at 0x4005B8: partition (quicksort.c:9)
==4698==    by 0x40079E: quicksort (quicksort.c:46)
==4698==    by 0x400803: quicksort (quicksort.c:50)
==4698==    by 0x400803: quicksort (quicksort.c:50)
==4698==    by 0x40081A: quicksort (quicksort.c:51)
==4698==    by 0x400803: quicksort (quicksort.c:50)
==4698==    by 0x400803: quicksort (quicksort.c:50)
==4698==    by 0x40086B: main (quicksort.c:61)
==4698== 
==4698== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff8
==4698== 
==4698== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4698==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF8
==4698==    at 0x400535: partition (quicksort.c:4)
==4698==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4698==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4698==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4698==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4698==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4698== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801fd8
==4698== 
==4698== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4698==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FD8
==4698==    at 0x4A256A5: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:58)
==4698==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==4698==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==4698==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==4698==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==4698==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==4698== 
==4698== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4698==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4698==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==4698== 
==4698== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4698== 
==4698== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4698== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==4698== ERROR SUMMARY: 14552 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: if you used `size_t` instead of `int` for indices, you might have recognized the need to decide whether `pivot` was a value or an index.

Comment: What's the output of valgrind?

Comment: Expanding on what EOF remarked, In `quicksort()` you have `pivot = a[low];`, so clearly `pivot` is a *value* from your array. Then in `partition()`, you have `while(l <= h && a[l] < a[pivot])`, so.. you're using a value from your array as an index into your array ? um.... Methinks you need to review whatever algorithm you're trying to implement and try again.

Comment: @WhozCraig I cannot find where exactly I used a value from my array to index the array. It is fair to say that `pivot` in `quicksort` is a value however I never use it to index my array (or at least I can't see where I'm doing so). It is also fair to say that `pivot` in my `partition` is an index however I never treat it as a value in this function (or I can't see where I'm doing so.) To further expand your last point, the `pivot` from `partition` is not the `pivot` from `quicksort`. The `pivot` in quicksort is but the `low` index.

Comment: @EOF Could you please explain a bit further? If you meant what WhozCraig said then could you please point me as to where I'm doing the mistake he pointed out?

Comment: @dbush Please check the update. Also you can use my comments as a reference as to which line numbers Valgrind is talking about

Comment: @Bula you're totally right. The choice of variable names was a teaser. I can peek at your vg-output. the line numbers are a little different with the posted code, but close enough. I generally don't use two indexes (low and high) when doing quicksort in C. Its honestly easier to adjust the base `a[]` via pointer arithmetic on recurse calls and just just pass a single sequence length. Maybe that's just me.

Comment: Fwiw, putting a seemingly innocent looking `printf("l=%d, h=%d, p=%d\n", l, h, pivot);` at the top of your partition function will be an interesting course worth pursuing.

Comment: @WhozCraig It is also quite interesting that if I try to print the first value (that is index 0) of the `*a` as the first line of the quicksort algorithm a lot of 0s invade my terminal. Maybe I just don't pass a good array to the algorithm?

Comment: @WhozCraig Check the answer if you are interested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the fact that the `if-else` statement at the bottom which decided whether to enter a recursion or return the index threw a small bug which I wasn't able to see.

If the condition was true then the function entered a recursion however once that returned, the function finished the `if-else` statement and returned -1 which then went ahead and was put into an index. This then threw the segmentation fault error